# jQuery AJAX bash telnet update div script continually

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bash, telnet

I have a bash script that connects to a telnet port; opens some diagnostics; exits; and, opens another telnet port.

To check if the script works fine, I can execute it with jQuery and AJAX, but I'm having trouble continually updating the `div` with the results.

I don't want to keep calling the same command when reloading the `php` to the `div`, but just want to refresh the results.

The bash script is pretty basic:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
sleep 2
echo diag gps info
sleep 2
echo exit
} | telnet 10.10.2.1 1700

telnet 10.10.2.1 1800
```

HTML/PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>diag stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="startGpsDiag" >Start gps diag</button>

<div id="results"></div>

</body>
<!-- <script langauge="JavaScript" src="{#javaScriptDir#}/jquery-min-1.8.js">    </script>   -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>   

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});       

    jQuery("#startGpsDiag").click(function  () { 
        //  alert('true');
        callGpsDiag();             
    });        

    function callGpsDiag(){
    jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "gpsDiag.php",
              data: "execGpsDiag=1",

              success: function(data) { 
              alert('success');
              jQuery('#results').html(data);

              setInterval(function() { 
                         jQuery('#results').html(data);
              },3000);    
              },
              error: function() {
              //    alert('fail');
              }                               
   });      
}            
});    
</script>
```

php logic file:

```
if(isset($_POST['execGpsDiag'])) {
    echo system('./gpsdiag.sh');
}
```

I may want to edit the bash file and remove the last telnet connection it's the one I want to monitor and move it to the `php` logic with an if we are not initially setting the diagnostics the monitor the port

I have also tried doing `echo system(telnet 10.10.1.2 1800)`
and tried the `setinterval` by itself to just load the monitoring port but could not get any results

if I run `gpsDiag.php` from command line with either just `echo system(telnet 10.10.1.2 1800)` or  `echo system('./gpsdiag.sh');` it works and displays results to screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timeout and call your function inside the timeout callback.

```
function callGpsDiag(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "gpsDiag.php",
    data: "execGpsDiag=1",
    success: function(data){ 
        alert('success');
        jQuery('#results').html(data);

        setTimeout(function(){ 
            callGpsDiag();
        },3000);
     },
     error: function() {
        //alert('fail');
     }
  });  

}
```

Comment: that helps it does keep calling the page but still can't get the output from the telnet port to display I know it's possible maybe I need to write the output to a file first?

Comment: Do I need to do something with the output buffer?

Comment: Consider replacing `telnet` with `nc` (you may have to install "netcat"). It works the same way, but is much less fuzzy when it comes to non-interactive use.

Comment: I think this is because your telnet and ajax calls are not in sync. I can think of two ways around this: 1) stop the bash from automatically opening/closing telnet and open a telnet only when its called by the php 2) as you said, writing the output to a file and then echoing the file output via php when the ajax request takes place

Comment: right now i'm testing just trying to echo the telnet 1800 shell output I'm looking into popen() possible so my main goal now is to display shell output....thanks for the help

Comment: I can't replace telnet with nc it's a propriatery box running montavista linux so it has minimal tools

Comment: @user1930591 im out for the night, hope this works. post an update with what happens. good luck

Comment: Got the telnet info to display had to add a sleep 5 to it I guess because it's interactive maybe?



bash
    {
    sleep 5
    } | telnet 10.10.2.1 1800

php
     echo system('./gpsdiag.sh');

I was thinking I would have to serialize or encode in json or something I discovered the longer the sleep the more data is displayed

Ideallly I'm going to add a start and capture to file so you can start view current status or write to file to view later

Thanks again for all the help

Comment: @user1930591 it would be great if you could share your final code (which works) as answer here so that others may find it helpful.